# some of the list functions afftect both lists(which I got shallow copy), while other not

Tags: python, list

I am confused with the following result that I am geting. It seems like some of the list functions afftect both lists(which I got shallow copy), while other not. When I remove one elemets from nested list it will affect the original list, while removing other elements will not. Append does not affect original list, assign does. Could you help me with understand this? Thanks!

```
original_list = [1, 2, 3,[1,4,3]]
copy_list = original_list[:]
copy_list[3][2]=6
copy_list.append(7)
copy_list.remove(2)
copy_list[2].remove(4)
original_list[3][0]=5
original_list[1]=34
print('original_list: \n', original_list)
print('copy_list: \n', copy_list)

output:
original_list: 
 [1, 34, 3, [5, 6]]
copy_list: 
 [1, 3, [5, 6], 7]
```

Comment: `copy_list` is a shallow copy. So changes to the nested elements affect both, but changes to the top-level elements only affect one list.

Comment: That's the difference between shallow and deep copy.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! I could not find the diference affect on the top level elements and nested elements. Could please give a refrence for it?

Comment: See the link I posted above, it has nice diagrams that show it.